# Angularjs must refresh page to see changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, breeze

What I have is simple CRUD operation. Items are listed on page, when user clicks button add, modal pops up, user enters data, and data is saved and should automatically (without refresh)be added to the list on page.

Service:

```
getAllIncluding: function(controllerAction, including) {
            var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from(controllerAction).expand(including);
            return manager.executeQuery(query).fail(getFailed);
        }, 

addExerciseAndCategories: function(data, initialValues) {
            var addedExercise = manager.createEntity("Exercise", initialValues);
            _.forEach(data, function(item) {
                manager.createEntity("ExerciseAndCategory", { ExerciseId: addedExercise._backingStore.ExerciseId, CategoryId: item.CategoryId });
            });
            saveChanges().fail(addFailed);

            function addFailed() {
                removeItem(items, item);
            }
        },
```

Controller:

```
 $scope.getAllExercisesAndCategories = function() {
        adminCrudService.getAllIncluding("ExercisesAndCategories", "Exercise,ExerciseCategory")
            .then(querySucceeded)
            .fail(queryFailed);

    };

     function querySucceeded(data) {

            $scope.queryItems = adminCrudService.querySucceeded(data);

            var exerciseIds = _($scope.queryItems).pluck('ExerciseId').uniq().valueOf();
            $scope.exerciseAndCategories = [];
            var createItem = function (id, exercise) {
                return {
                    ExerciseId: id,
                    Exercise : exercise,
                    ExerciseCategories: []
                };
            };

            // cycle through ids
            _.forEach(exerciseIds, function (id) {
                // get all the queryItems that match
                var temp = _.where($scope.queryItems, {
                    'ExerciseId': id
                });
                // go to the next if nothing was found.
                if (!temp.length) return;
                // create a new (clean) item
                var newItem = createItem(temp[0].ExerciseId, temp[0].Exercise);
                // loop through the queryItems that matched
                _.forEach(temp, function (i) {
                    // if the category has not been added , add it.
                    if (_.indexOf(newItem.ExerciseCategories, i.ExerciseCategory) < 0) {
                        newItem.ExerciseCategories.push(i.ExerciseCategory);
                    }
                });
                // Add the item to the collection
                $scope.items.push(newItem);
            });


            $scope.$apply();

        }
```

Here is how I add new data from controller:

```
 adminCrudService.addExerciseAndCategories($scope.selectedCategories, { Name: $scope.NewName, Description: $scope.NewDesc });
```

So my question is, why  list isn't updated in real time (when I hit save I must refresh page).

**EDIT**

Here is my querySuceeded

```
querySucceeded: function (data) {
            items = [];
            data.results.forEach(function(item) {
                items.push(item);
            });
            return items;


        }
```

**EDIT 2**

**I believe I've narrowed my problem !**

So [PW Kad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1200803/pw-kad) lost two hours with me trying to help me to fix this thing (ad I thank him very very very much for that), but unfortunately with no success. We mostly tried to fix my service, so when I returned to my PC, I've again tried to fix it. I believe my service is fine. (I've made some changes as Kad suggested in his answer).
I believe problem is in controller, I've logged $scope.items, and when I add new item they don't change, after that I've logged $scope.queryItems, and I've noticed that they change after adding new item (without refresh ofc.). So probably problem will be solved by somehow $watching  $scope.queryItems after loading initial data, but at the moment I'm not quite sure how to do this.

Comment: Just as a heads up, that is an absolute ton of code that you posted and it is very time consuming to dig through all of it.  You may have more success if you reduce it to the code that you are having the problem with, identify where the problem occurs, and ask for specific help.

Comment: It is more useful to put those code in an online demo to save your time as well as our time.

Comment: Thanks, for advice, I'll do that

Comment: @PWKad I've edited post and deleted all unnecessary code

Comment: @hyperN Btw, do you use mvc 4 web api?

Comment: @sza Yes, same way it is showed in breeze samples. With other controllers I don't have problems, they are simpler than this one, but principle is same, so I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Where is your querySucceeded function on your service?  And why are you getting the results back and then sending it back to the service?

Comment: Also why do you need to call scope.apply?

Comment: @PWKad, I've edited post and added querySucceeded  code, and you're right I don't need to call scope.apply, and to which part are you referring  when you say I am getting result back and sending it back to service?

Comment: Let's take this to chat real quick...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35664/discussion-between-pw-kad-and-hypern)

Comment: @PWKad please can you see my last edit :)

Comment: Sure give me a bit - if you get a chance to try to replicate the issue in fiddle

Comment: I've tried to recreate problem in jsfiddle, but I'm getting error for lodash (underscore alternative), and I've just pasted code which worsk fine in VS, here is link http://jsfiddle.net/v87EM/26/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I've managed to solve my problem ! Not sure if this is right solution but it works now.
I've moved everything to my service, which now looks like this:

```
function addCategoriesToExercise(tempdata) {
        var dataToReturn = [];
        var exerciseIds = _(tempdata).pluck('ExerciseId').uniq().valueOf();
        var createItem = function (id, exercise) {
            return {
                ExerciseId: id,
                Exercise: exercise,
                ExerciseCategories: []
            };
        };

        // cycle through ids
        _.forEach(exerciseIds, function (id) {
            // get all the queryItems that match
            var temp = _.where(tempdata, {
                'ExerciseId': id
            });
            // go to the next if nothing was found.
            if (!temp.length) return;
            // create a new (clean) item
            var newItem = createItem(temp[0].ExerciseId, temp[0].Exercise);
            // loop through the queryItems that matched
            _.forEach(temp, function (i) {
                // if the category has not been added , add it.
                if (_.indexOf(newItem.ExerciseCategories, i.ExerciseCategory) < 0) {
                    newItem.ExerciseCategories.push(i.ExerciseCategory);
                }
            });
            // Add the item to the collection
            dataToReturn.push(newItem);
        });

        return dataToReturn;
    }

    addExerciseAndCategories: function (data, initialValues) {
        newItems = [];

        var addedExercise = manager.createEntity("Exercise", initialValues);

        _.forEach(data, function (item) {
            var entity = manager.createEntity("ExerciseAndCategory", { ExerciseId: addedExercise._backingStore.ExerciseId, CategoryId: item.CategoryId });
            items.push(entity);
            newItems.push(entity);

        });
        saveChanges().fail(addFailed);

        var itemsToAdd = addCategoriesToExercise(newItems);

        _.forEach(itemsToAdd, function (item) {
            exerciseAndCategories.push(item);
        });

        function addFailed() {
            removeItem(items, item);
        }
    }

 getAllExercisesAndCategories: function () {
            var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from("ExercisesAndCategories").expand("Exercise,ExerciseCategory");
            return manager.executeQuery(query).then(getSuceeded).fail(getFailed);

        },

function getSuceeded(data) {
        items = [];
        data.results.forEach(function (item) {
            items.push(item);
        });

        exerciseAndCategories = addCategoriesToExercise(items);

        return exerciseAndCategories;
    }
```

And in controller I have only this:

```
   $scope.getAllExercisesAndCategories = function () {
        adminExerciseService.getAllExercisesAndCategories()
            .then(querySucceeded)
            .fail(queryFailed);

    };
      function querySucceeded(data) {
            $scope.items = data;

            $scope.$apply();

        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Alright, I am going to post an answer that should guide you on how to tackle your issue.  The issue does not appear to be with Breeze, nor with Angular, but the manner in which you have married the two up.  I say this because it is important to understand what you are doing in order to understand the debug process.

**Creating an entity adds it to the cache with an entityState of isAdded** - that is a true statement, don't think otherwise.

Now for your code...

You don't *have* to chain your query execution with a promise, but in your case you are returning the data to your controller, and then passing it right back into some function in your service, which wasn't listed in your question.  I added a function to replicate what yours *probably* looks like.

```
getAllIncluding: function(controllerAction, including) {
            var query = breeze.EntityQuery.from(controllerAction).expand(including);
            return manager.executeQuery(query).then(querySucceeded).fail(getFailed);

            function querySucceeded(data) {
                return data.results;
            }
        },
```

Now in your controller simply handle the results -

```
$scope.getAllExercisesAndCategories = function() {
    adminCrudService.getAllIncluding("ExercisesAndCategories", "Exercise,ExerciseCategory")
        .then(querySucceeded)
        .fail(queryFailed);
};

 function querySucceeded(data) {
        // Set your object directly to the data.results, because that is what we are returning from the service
        $scope.queryItems = data;  
        $scope.exerciseAndCategories = [];
```

Last, let's add the properties we create the entity and see if that gives Angular a chance to bind up properly -

```
_.forEach(data, function(item) { 
    var e = manager.createEntity("ExerciseAndCategory"); 
    e.Exercise = addedExercise; e.Category: item.Category; 
});
```